# Analytic semigroup whose are uniformly bounded with 0 in resolvent of A

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Are analytic semigroups $T(t)$ defined on a Banach space $X$, that is uniformly bounded with $0 \in \rho (A)$ the resolvent set of the infinitesimal generator A, have this property:
$$ \lim_{t \to 0 } \|T(t) - I\|=0.  \qquad (*)$$
I know that the property (*) is the definition of uniformly continuous semigroup, and in this case, $A$ bounded, which is not the case in my situation.
In many papers concerning functional differential equations, the authors use this property while saying "by the strong continuity of $T(t)$ "?
does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Your property $(\ast)$ implies that the generator is a bounded operator. This is quite rare in PDEs. When people use strong continuity of a strongly continuous semigroup with infinitesimal generator $A$, they generally only use the fact

$$ \forall x\in \overline{\mathrm{D}(A)}^{\lVert\cdot\rVert_X}\text{, }\lVert T(t) x - x\rVert_{X}\xrightarrow[t\rightarrow 0_+]{} 0.$$

Which is generally sufficient, regardless of whether $0\in\rho(A)$ or not.

Comment: This is a different and really weaker property than the uniform continuity of the strongly continuous semigroup (w.r.t. the operator norm), since it holds for any nice enough unbounded operator generating a strongly continuous semigroup.

Comment: @ToGle Yes, that is what I know. but does this property (*) have anything to do with the continuity in the uniform operator topology?

Comment: I am just guessing: Assuming Infinitesimal generator is defined by $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} ||\frac{T(t)-T(0)}{t}-A|| = 0$, we have: $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{||T(t)-T(0)||}{||t||}  = ||A|| \implies \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}  ||T(t)-T(0)|| = 0$ for $||A|| < \infty$. We also have $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{||(T(t)-T(0))x||}{||t||}  = ||Ax|| \implies \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}  ||(T(t)-T(0))x|| = 0$ as long as $||Ax|| < \infty$.

Comment: cont... If $X$ is finite dimensional then $||A|| = \infty \implies t ||Ax|| = \infty$ for some $x$ with $||x|| = 1$ $\implies \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} ||(T(t) - T(0))x|| = \infty$. Your problematic case to conclude would be when $B(0,1)$ is not compact (infinite dimensional) and $||A|| = \infty$

Comment: cont... for infinite dimensional and unbounded operator $A$, we will have $||Ax_n|| \rightarrow \infty$ with $||x_n||=1$ and $x_n$ is not cauchy. Now if $0\in \rho(A)$ then there exists a bounded inverse $inv(A)$ on the image . This leads to a contradiction if u assume $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} ||\frac{T^{-1}(t) -I}{t} - inv(A) || =0$ and $\lim_{ t \rightarrow 0}  ||T(t)|| < \infty$.

Comment: @Balajisb Thanks. The last case is the main problem, generally, property (*) is not satisfied. even if we are talking about the continuity in the uniform topology.